# Fragment$InstantiationException on inflating androidx fragment from android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, androidx

I'm getting the following exception:

```
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.android.btVspTest.StageCollectionFragment that is not a Fragment
```

The exception triggers within the following call to `android.app.Activity.setContentView` from `onCreate()` of my `VspTestActivity` class, which extends `android.app.Activity`:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_vsp_test);`

My `com.example.android.btVspTest.StageCollectionFragment` extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. I am guessing the issue has to do with incompatibility beween `android.app.Activity` and `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. Is there a fix or work-around?

Application level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    /*implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'*/
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
}
```

activity_vsp_test.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/test_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_huge"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test_connect_button"
            android:layout_width="126dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/connect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test_disconnect_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/disconnect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test_bluetooth_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="startBluetoothActivity"
            android:text="Bluetooth" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vsp_test_connection_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/disconnected" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_result_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- 2 irrelevant linear layouts with buttons in them removed -->

    <fragment class="com.example.android.btVspTest.StageCollectionFragment"
        android:id="@+id/test_stage_collection_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

StageCollectionFragment.java:

```
package com.example.android.btVspTest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy;

public class StageCollectionFragment extends Fragment implements TabConfigurationStrategy {
    // When requested, this adapter returns a StageFragment,
    // representing an object in the collection.
    StageCollectionAdapter demoCollectionAdapter;
    ViewPager2 viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_stage_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        demoCollectionAdapter = new StageCollectionAdapter(this);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.test_stage_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(demoCollectionAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.test_stage_tab_layout);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, this).attach();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
        tab.setText("OBJECT " + (position + 1));
    }
}
```

VspTestActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.btVspTest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.ActivityMessageDataKey;
import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.BluetoothActivity;
import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.DeviceListActivity;
import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.R;
import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.enums.ConnectionState;
import com.example.android.bluetoothvsp.enums.TestState;
import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;
import com.example.android.common.logger.LogWrapper;
import com.example.android.common.logger.MessageOnlyLogFilter;

public class VspTestActivity extends Activity
{
    /**
     * Debugging.
     */
    private static final String TAG = "VspTestActivity";

    /**
     * UI elements.
     */
    private TextView mConnectionTextView;
    private TextView mTestResultTextView;
    private Button mConnectButton;
    private Button mDisconnectButton;
    private Button mSynchronousTestButton;
    private Button mHostSpamButton;
    private Button mReaderSpamButton;
    private Button mBothSpamButton;

    /**
     * Objects provided by Android to facilitate Bluetooth operations.
     */
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    /**
     * Manger used to start and handle the communication tests.
     */
    private BluetoothVspTestManager mVspTestManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vsp_test);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

    // Irrelevant code removed
    }

    // Irrelevant code removed

    @Override
    protected  void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Irrelevant code removed
    }

    // Irrelevant code removed
}
```

Some of the code is copy->paste->edit of example at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2, with following mapping:

- My StageCollectionFragment is their CollectionDemoFragment
- My StageFragment is their DemoObjectFragment

That developer.android.com example unfortunately isn't complete as the layout resources are missing. I haven't been able to find a full example on the internet, of combining TabLayout & ViewPager2.

I'm trying to do something like the draft screen at https://imgur.com/a/k8Tr52y?. I would eventually have 4 to 5 tabs with actual meaningful tab titles, with the tabs being added dynamically, and specific fragments in each of the tabs.

Comment: `VspTestActivity` should extend `AppCompatActivity` and you have to use `supportFragmentManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since part of your code is using AndroidX libraries, I'll assume you are okay with going all-in and use AndroidX exclusively. You should. Right now, you are mixing old and new Android libraries and that's not a good thing. Simply do the following when declaring (pay attention to the import statements):

your activity:

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

`public class VspTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

and your fragment:

`import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

`public class StageCollectionFragment extends Fragment ...`

Even easier is to let Android Studio do it all for you. Just select Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX (on the Mac)

Comment: The manual editing fixed it, thank you. I tried the Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX on Windows 10 PC with Android Studio v4.0, and I got to a popup reading "No Usage Found in the project".

Comment: glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

Your activity must extend `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity),

> Base class for activities that want to use the support-based
>   Fragments.

Also from [Fragment's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment),

> - Your activity must extend FragmentActivity
> - You must call FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() to get the    FragmentManager